# Node.js REST Interface Backbone Collections

Tags: rest, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following problem:

I have a an `account` collection on my serverside (mongoose), i use express-resource for the  REST API.

Now i have several other objects (Project, Organization, Task) containing a member list (Array of ObjectIds) which are all subsets of the `account` collection.

A MarionetteJS application is dealing with my clientside collections.

I am looking for a way to avoid calls to the API. The goal is to get collections by a call to the api.

Some ideas i have:

- Adding a resource to each object like

  ```
  /api/organization/:organizationId/members/
  /api/organization/:organizationId/project/:projectId/members/
  ```
- Adding parameters to the base resource like

  ```
  /api/accounts/?ids=id
  ```
- Fetching the biggest set of accounts possible (from organization) and getting the other subsets from this collection (clientside).
- Populating the members in the member list on the server side
- Single Account loading. Iterating throug the list of members and fetch each member.

Is there a kind of best practice? I know the first option is maybe the best but maybe there is a option i missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you have structured your Mongoose database. If the member list is included on the Organization, Project or Task document, a query of the document will give you the list you need, without having to look for the specific field you're interested in.

If you coded the list as a different document (which sounds like a SQL practice), you will need to set up a new resource on Node to get the list of members. In this case, your first option sounds like a good one in terms of URL structure but the implementation (loading on server side or client side) depends on the characteristics of the project. By using Node I guess that you want a small server and a heavy client (the usual scenario), so you will end up doing it on the client.

As for good practice, MongoDB is a document-oriented database. In order to get the best of it stop thinking about entities and relationships and think about the documents they will serve. Having data duplicated in many parts is very common. Each collection is a type of document so every time the client wants some data to show it will fetch a document containing all the information it needs.

Look for MongoDB patterns online, there are many good sources. If you prefer a book, look for Chodorow's Definitive Guide or Copeland's Applied Design Patterns.